# Infinite loop on combination of RewriteRules

Tags: apache, codeigniter, loops, mod-rewrite, infinite

So I'm setting up SVN on my home server (Ubuntu 9.1), and want the ability to view any changes made to my CodeIgniter app immediately.

So, my working copy lives in /home/myname/environments/development/appname.

My Vhost is accessible at dev.appname.myname.ca, and the config looks like this:

```
 DocumentRoot /home/myname/environments/development/
 ServerName dev.myname.ca
 ServerAlias dev.*.myname.ca

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.([^\.]+)\.myname\.ca
 RewriteCond /home/myname/environments/development/%1/trunk/ -d
 RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/trunk/public/$1
```

So, going to dev.appname.myname.ca would point to /home/myname/environments/development/appname/trunk/public.

Now, this being a CodeIgniter app, I need to redirect all requests from public/ to public/index.php, so the .htaccess file in public/ is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have this part in an .htaccess file because on a live production site, I won't have access to the server config so I'd need to override it.

The problem is now that I'm getting a loop of redirects and ultimately a 500 error.

From /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
redirected from r->uri = /appname/trunk/public/index.php/appname/trunk/public/index.php/appname/trunk/public/index.php/appname/trunk/public/index.php/appname/trunk/public/index.php/appname/trunk/public/index.php/appname/trunk/public/index.php/
```

How can I redirect the request to the proper public/ directory (in this case, /home/myname/environments/development/appname/trunk/publc) and THEN direct all requests from public/ to public/index.php?

I know it's a long-winded question - thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your RewriteRule is backwards from what you actually want.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This will turn "dirA/dirB/dirC/" into "index.php/dirA/dirB/dirC". On the subsequent HTTP request, this will satisfy the condition and the rule will be applied again. And again, and again...

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/?$ $1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: If you do that CodeIgniter will never work. The [L] flag means it will redirect to index.php then do no more re-directs.

Answer (score 0):

AS Phil mentioned you should use the rewrite rules from here http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

For some debugging you can add following lines to your httpd.conf or virtual host conf.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
</IfModule>
```

With

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
```

you can check the rewrite rules and some errors. You can also change the Level to 9. Take care with this option. It produce a lot of information. It's sometimes rely helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Try using something a little less crazy, you should not need to redirect from public/ to public/index.php as Apache will do that for you.

The CodeIgniter Wiki shows how to [create the ultimate CodeIgniter .htaccess](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/).